# VueJS & VUEX: Shortening JS Code

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I love clean and simple code.

So I like to shorten these lines of javascript so they don't seem so cluttered.

My vuex-mutation code:

```
editEvent(state) {
  if (
    state.form.time !== '' &&
    state.form.date !== '' &&
    state.form.event !== '' &&
    state.form.artist !== '' &&
    state.form.organizer !== '' &&
    state.form.location !== ''
  ) {
    const event = {
      time: state.form.time,
      date: state.form.date,
      event: state.form.event,
      artist: state.form.artist,
      organizer: state.form.organizer,
      location: state.form.location
    }
    events.child(state.currentEventKey).update(event)
    state.form.time = ''
    state.form.date = ''
    state.form.event = ''
    state.form.artist = ''
    state.form.organizer = ''
    state.form.location = ''
    state.currentEventKey = null
    state.showForm = false
  }
}
```

and here another one:

```
populateEventForm(state, payload) {
  state.form.time = payload.event.time
  state.form.date = payload.event.date
  state.form.event = payload.event.event
  state.form.artist = payload.event.artist
  state.form.organizer = payload.event.organizer
  state.form.location = payload.event.location
  state.currentEventKey = payload.key
  state.showForm = true
}
```

How can I improve this ?!??!

Comment: This belongs more on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 4):

This is pseudo code for the most part. Somewhere store your common properties.

```
const props = ["time", "date", "event", "artist", "organizer", "location"]
```

Then use that in your functions.

```
function editEvent(state) {
  // check to see if every property exists on the state
  if (!props.every(p => state.form[p] !== '')) return
  // build the event object
  const event = props.reduce((acc, p) => acc[p] = state.form[p], {})
  // I don't know where "events" comes from-- I left this alone
  events.child(state.currentEventKey).update(event)
  // clear each property
  props.forEach(p => state.form[p] = '')
  // clear your misc. props
  state.currentEventKey = null
  state.showForm = false
}

function populateEventForm(state, payload) {
  props.forEach(p => state.form[p] = payload.event[p])
  state.currentEventKey = payload.key
  state.showForm = true
}
```

Please be advised, since you posted this as a Vue/Vuex question, you *may* need to use [Vue.set](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set) instead of an indexer in cases like the `event` object being built. It's hard for me to tell from the limited code you posted. In that case it would be something like

```
const event = props.reduce((acc, p) => {
    Vue.set(acc, p, state.form[p])
    return acc
}, {})
```